# Make pragma with string from array at compile time

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#pragma code_seg(push, ".text$EBC000")
```

code_seg prama changes function order in .text section. I want to have a general macro like `CHANGE_FUNCTION_ORDER` that uses `__COUNTER__` macro to everytime get different string that will be used for code_seg pragma.

```
const char *array = {".text$EBC002", ".text$EBC000", ".text$EBC003"};
#define CHANGE_FUNCTION_ORDER __pragma(code_seg(push, ????)) // how do I tell compiler to use string at __ COUNTER__ index from array
```

The idea is from http://lallouslab.net/2018/03/26/shuffling-function-addresses-in-c-c-with-msvc/

Comment: The preprocessor runs before any code is evaluated.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible if preprocessor can understand that data won't change

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't know anything about arrays, array indexes, pointers or string literals.

Comment: How then int a = 3 + 3; in assembly would be like mov eax, 6h

Comment: But that's not the preprocessor, that's the compilers optimizer which runs *far* after the preprocessor. I recommend [this translation phase reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) to help you understand why the preprocessor can't help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using Boost.Preprocessor:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>

#define CODE_SEGMENTS (".text$EBC002", ".text$EBC000", ".text$EBC003")
#define CHANGE_FUNCTION_ORDER __pragma(code_seg(push, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(__COUNTER__, CODE_SEGMENTS))
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a14ef3b0b9fa680)